# When should [javascript-events] be used, and when should [events] be used?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Today, there are [5087](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/events+javascript) questions with [events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/events) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [9298](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-events+javascript) questions with [javascript-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-events) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), and [462](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-events+javascript+events) with [events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/events), [javascript-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-events) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) for good measure.

There's no documentation in either [events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/events) or [javascript-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-events) about when either tag should be used as opposed to the other.

If asking a question about JavaScript, when should [events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/events) be used, and when should [javascript-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-events) be used? If there's no difference, should Javascript questions with [events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/events) be retagged to [javascript-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-events)?

Comment: I think events is more generic than the javascript-events, the later is more subject related

Comment: I wonder what's the difference between javascript-events and plain old javascript?

Comment: I guess all javascript-events questions should be retagged javascript+events, though not manually. Not sure it's worth a CMs or devs time though.

Comment: @Braiam If someone doesn't grasp the concept of a "function as a first-class object", `javascript-events` is indistinguishable from sufficiently advanced technology.

Comment: I guess most of these should be retagged to [[tag:dom-events]]

Comment: @Bergi It's not something that can be assumed -- what if the question is about event mechanisms provided by some library, such as jQuery's event methods?

Comment: @ZevSpitz Then use [[tag:jquery-events]] instead. Of course it cannot be assumed that all of them relate to the DOM.

Answer (score 8):

There are other programming languages that use the concept of `events`. My opinion is that this is a matter of good use of the person that is asking the question. I don't think that having a tag named `javascript-events` is helpful. The concept of `event` should be the same no matter the programming language that is being used. Events are Events, simple. I believe that there should not be a tag named `javascript-events`. Questions about events specifically asking for javascript events, should have two task separately, javascript and events.

Answer (score 8):

Since the Javascript language has no event constructs, [javascript-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-events) has no meaning.

[events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/events) only has meaning when the question is also tagged with the specific library/host eventing API -- [yui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yui)+[events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/events) or [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js)+[events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/events). When available, it is better to use the API's events tag -- [backbone-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backbone-events), [jquery-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-events).

(N.B. Microsoft JScript does have language constructs for event handling as detailed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974564.aspx) (in the section labelled **Automagic**), and as such might be a candidate for [javascript-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-events).)

Comment: "the Javascript language has no event constructs" ... huh?  JavaScript has *more* than one event construct: it has one event construct per browser ;)  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535863(v=vs.85).aspx, etc.

Comment: @machineghost I think Zev was saying that those are not part of the language Javascript (which can be compiled or run in many contexts), they are part of the DOM, so it would be better to use the more specific tag dom-events. In my opinion, dom-events is a useless tag though. I would prefer to see three separates tags used: javascript, dom, and events.

Comment: @Paulpro Exactly. RE: [tag:dom-events] I agree, but that is the subject of a different meta post.